# File Upload Forms: Security

Tags: web-development, security

SO I'm building an application for uploading files. We're paying scientists to contribute information on pests, diseases and bugs (for Plants). We need the ability to drag and drop a file to upload it.

The question becomes since the users will be authicentated and setup by us, will it be necessarcy to include a virus scanner to prevent the uploading and insertition of malicious files.

How important is this?

Comment: What kind of files? Pictures? Documents? Presentations? Zip files? Executables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Always. Never consider not scanning the files. The scanner may not be perfect, but at least you have something that can be updated when new "bad file" cases are found, rather than nothing at all. The people uploading the files might be, under good intentions and unknowingly, uploading a file that has a virus or malicious code in it. Even if you never handle the file in a way that can harm you, it could harm the computers of the people who retrieve the files. Think of it this way: you're using authentication to help protect access to the files, whereas  you would use virus scanner to help protect the safety of the computers that will use or handle the files. They are two different things that need to be taken into consideration.

Comment: This.  Just because you're paranoid doesn't mean they AREN'T  still out to get you (or your customers).

Comment: What solutions exist to do this in a web app?

Comment: I don't know any off-hand. I had to "deal with" one  previously, but it was handled by another group of people in the company, and I don't remember what it was called.